# Error "sys/videoio.h - not found" OpenCV 3.1.0

Tags: linux, opencv, ffmpeg, libav

I using Elementary OS and I'm trying to install OpenCV 3.1.0, I follow the instructions of http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html 
Also, I have installed libav 11.7 and ffmpeg 3.1.3 
 
but, after cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
I get: 
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h 
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - found 
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h 
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found 
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h 
-- **Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found** 
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h 
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found 
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h 
-- **Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found** 
-- checking for module 'libgphoto2' 
--   package 'libgphoto2' not found 
And after make, 
I get: 
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.1.0: referencia a `av_frame_alloc' sin definir <br>
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.1.0: referencia a`av_frame_free' sin definir 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_test_video] Error 1 

make[1]: *** [modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/all] Error 2

someone who can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this [issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6262#issuecomment-260320054), which works for me.
My problem is solved by set `-DWITH_V4AL=OFF` and `-DWITH_LIBV4L=ON`

> After I set WITH_V4L = OFF but still keep WITH_LIBV4L = ON, the configuring skipped the searching of 'sys/videoio.h', and the compilation worked.